# cron job for codeigniter in parallels cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am currently using codeigniter in parallels cpanel. I want to setup cronjob. In schedule task section,

```
command  : wget <website domain>/calendar/performance/?id=1
```

But my cronjob doesn't work.
Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/cli.html

You should try with something like

```
path/to/php  -f  /path/to/project/index.php   calendar   performance  1
```